# Specific way of requiring one of two fields in django model definition

Tags: python, django

I have model `MyModel` with fields `field1` and `field2`. I want to require either one of these two fields. How can I do this?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(?)
    field2 = models.TextField(?)
```

I am looking for a specific, best-practice way that I have seen but forgotten, not the overriding `clean` function method. I do remember the method overriding some function, but I don't think it was `clean`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Overriding `clean` *is* the way to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As commented use clean

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    field2 = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if not cleaned_data.get('field1') and not cleaned_data.get('field2'):  # This will check for None or Empty
            raise ValidationError({'field1': 'Even one of field1 or field2 should have a value.'})
```

Comment: I consider this the hacky way.

Comment: @Mike Johnson : Please explain

Comment: @MikeJohnson That's not hacky, that's the way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: #Mike Jonson : take a look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other  , it validates on the form but same issue

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of `unique_together`. I'll use the `clean` method

Comment: `ValidationError` needs to be imported from `django.core.exceptions`

Answer (score 36):

This is an old question, but since this was the first hit for me when I searched for "django model field require one of two", I should point out that while overriding `clean()` may have been a good practise 3 years ago, Django's support for database constraint definitions in the `Meta` class is a much better choice for this these days.  [This tutorial](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/03/25/django-check-constraints-one-field-set/) put me on the right path, but here's a code sample from our model:

```
class MyModel:

    thing1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    thing2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_thing1_or_thing2",
                check=(
                    models.Q(thing1__isnull=True, thing2__isnull=False)
                    | models.Q(thing1__isnull=False, thing2__isnull=True)
                ),
            )
        ]
```

Comment: I think to be precise ones would have to switch `name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_thing1_and_or_thing2",` to `name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_thing1_or_thing2",` or am I mistaken?

Comment: @xtlc the `name` is just for your convenience, the `check` is what matters. That said it does seem like the `and` is a typo.

Comment: @Dave you're correct.  I've removed the `and_`.

Comment: I like this one better than the accepted answer. Being a model constraint, it is more elegant to do that on the database level

Comment: This throws an `IntegrityError` when none of the two fields are specified in a form (Django 3.2 LTS). Proper handling in `clean()` is still required.