# Django model constraint for ensuring one or both fields are not empty strings

Tags: django

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66860132/250962) I want to set up a constraint on a Django model that ensures one or both of two fields are set. However, while that answer assumes the empty fields are `NULL`, in my case they are always empty strings. I'm not sure how to check for that in the constraint.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class Person(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=False, default="")
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=False, default="")

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_firstname_and_or_surname",
                check=(
                    Q(firstname__exact="", surname__exact!="")
                    | Q(firstname__exact!="", surname__exact="")
                    | Q(firstname__exact!="", surname__exact!="")
                ),
            )
        ]
```

This should work except that, unlike `surname_isnull=False`,  `surname__exact!=""` isn't valid syntax.

I know that if I had a queryset I could use `exclude(surname__exact="")` to mean "is not empty", but I'm not sure how to do that in this constraint with `Q()` expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `~` as the [`NOT` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
check = (
    Q(Q(firstname__exact="") & ~Q(surname__exact="")) | 
    Q(~Q(firstname__exact="") & Q(surname__exact="")) | 
    Q(~Q(firstname__exact="") & ~Q(surname__exact=""))
)
```

Comment: I've never noticed that, thanks! I should have RTFM. However, with that, the migration generates an SQL syntax error. The SQL it's trying to execute is: ```ALTER TABLE `Person` ADD CONSTRAINT `app_person_firstname_and_or_surname` CHECK (((`firstname` =  AND NOT (`surname` = )) OR (NOT (`firstname` = ) AND `surname` = ) OR (NOT (`firstname` = ) AND NOT (`surname` = ))));``` Strange.

Comment: This is really strange, looks even like a bug to me that the empty string seems to vanish.. Maybe check what happens in a simple case with only on `Q()` object or some other string?

Comment: Yes, very odd. If I only do `check=(Q(firstname__exact="")),` then the SQL is to add ```CHECK (`firstname` = )```. I'll try filing a bug report.

Comment: The ticket is here, in case it's of interest: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33802

Comment: This is really strange... also tried to reproduce it but couldn't. Maybe it's related to `mysqlclient` or something like that? Is this the SQL you get if you run `python manage.py sqlmigrate <your app> <migration number>`?

Comment: If you are interested in debugging it you could probably set a breakpoint around here https://github.com/django/django/blob/94d8ed55fa8e181b98f818a1b2805c66943cfeec/django/db/models/constraints.py#L59 somewhere and see where the invalid SQL is created...